# how to run AutoArchive on outlook for a single Folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Does anybody know how to force outlook to AutoArchive Contents for a single folder, in this case it is my Calendar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunatly you can't auto archive a single folder in Outlook. I am not sure if there is a third party application that will allow it.

According to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830119) Microsoft document you can only change the folder settings but not AutoArchive an individual folder.

However you can do a manual Auto Archive, and switch of AutoArchive for all other folders except the calendar.

In Outlook 2007 you can do a manual Archive from the Mailbox Cleanup screen.

- Tools
- Mailbox Cleanup
- Auto Archive

You can however export your calendar and then import it into your AutoArchive PST. You can then do a cleanup on your calendar by cleaning out the export file and then reimpoting it into your main calendar.

Comment: Yes, i thought of the manual auto archive option, the risk is you need to check the settings for each folder, and with many folders, it is a problem.

Comment: Ultimately that is how i ended up doing, if i dont get a better response as a long term solution, i will accept yours as the solution

Answer (score 7):

You can archive a single folder in Outook 2010 - File - Info - Cleanup Tools - Archive - pick folder to archive

Answer (score 4):

You can click File, Archive, and it will bring up a dialog/wizard, there will be option buttons, choose "Archive this folder and all subfolders" and the folder list will become active listing all of your folders. Then you can browse the list of folders and choose which folder you want to archive. Then you tell it where to archive to, and archive. Calendar is an option.

Answer (score 1):

Am I understanding the question correctly by restating it as "I want to use AutoArchive, but only for one folder and no others"?

If so, this can be done. However, you need to manually disable AutoArchive on all other folders. The easiest way is to move to Folder List, and right click on each folder (Contacts, deleted, inbox, sent items etc) choose properties, and click the AutoArchive tab. Then choose "Do not archive items in this folder".

Then make sure that the folder you want to archive (Calendar) has "Archive items using the default settings".

However, if you want to AutoArchive your Calendar to one PST, and other mail to another PST, this can't be done automatically, only manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can also archive one folder (or everything) with a nifty *Outlook Macro*.

```
'This example uses inbox, but you can convert it.
Set myInbox = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set archFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(CurrentArchiveFolder)

For Each myItem In myInbox.Items
    If ShouldArchive(myItem) Then
        Debug.Print "Moving Item: " & myItem.Subject
        myItem.Move archFolder
    End If
Next myItem
```

Just be sure to check the recurrence pattern (call **myItem.GetRecurrancePattern** to get it) to make sure the item is not still recurring.

**Note:** Outlook Macros have been known to have a negative effect on sanity, and should never be used in production applications.  Use at your own risk.

Comment: Unfortunately a calendar is just not the same as a normal mails folder, some items need to be moved, and some should not like, recurring items. Otherwise i would'nt even bother about AutoArchiving